# FFmpeg - How do i get the extradata required to open the ALAC Codec?

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg

I am wondering how to get the extradata from an ALAC media file using the FFmpeg library without having to manually parse the file?

I setup initially with:

```
avformat_open_input(&formatContext, pszFileName, 0, 0);
avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, NULL);
av_find_best_stream(formatContext, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, &codec, 0);
codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
```

Currently I am able to detect and find the ALAC codec but it fails to open the codec returning AVERROR_INVALIDDATA, which comes from the **extradata** and **extradata_size** not being set.

```
avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL);
```

The FFmpeg documentation states that some codecs require **extradata** and **extradata_size** to be set to the codec's specifications. But shouldn't this data be set by **avformat_find_stream_info**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `extradata` is populated during either `avformat_open_input()` or `avformat_find_stream_info()`. However, it populates it in a field you didn't use. You need the following code:

```
avformat_open_input(&formatContext, pszFileName, 0, 0);
avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, NULL);
int audioStreamIndex = av_find_best_stream(formatContext, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, &codec, 0);
codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
avcodec_copy_context(codecContext, formatContext->streams[audioStreamIndex]->codec);
avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL);
```

The relevant extra line is `avcodec_copy_context()`, which copies the data from the `libavformat` demuxer (in `formatContext->streams[]`) to the copy of that context (`codecContext`) that you will use for decoding using the decoder in `libavcodec`.

Comment: Thanks, i can now open the codec but upon decoding i get:
V/FFMPEG: invalid zero block size of 33 4096 4065
V/FFMPEG: unknown prediction type: 3
V/FFMPEG: invalid zero block size of 26 4096 4094
V/FFMPEG: syntax element unsupported: 5.
Possible causes?

Comment: Can you post complete code and a sample input file somewhere?

Comment: Managed to fix it. Once again was a problem in the implementation. I wasn't calling **av_read_frame(formatContext, &packet)** before decoding with avcodec_decode_audio4.